# Uncertainty on standard deviation and rms

Tags: uncertainty

Say I have a time-series of a parameter $y(t)$. Each value of $y(t)$ has an uncertainty of $\epsilon_y$ due to how it was measured. What is the uncertainty on the calculated rms or standard deviation?

As an example, say I was measuring a voltage signal $V(t)$. The voltage measurement device has a specified uncertainty ($\epsilon_V$) of 0.5%. If I want to say the AC voltage signal had an RMS of 240 volts $\pm \epsilon_{RMS}$, how would I know the uncertainty on the rms?

Comment: By uncertainty do you mean standard deviation or is Ey a noise term or is this a reference to something else? Is this series independent or (as is more typical for time series), related over time?

Comment: Ey is an uncertainty on my term. For example, say I was measuring an AC voltage signal, I would have an uncertainty on my voltage measurement (Ev). If I work out the RMS of the voltage, it will have some uncertainty (presumably based on Ev)?

Comment: what does the uncertainty actually quantify in your case?

Comment: My voltage measurement (in this example only) is 95% confident of its measurement being within 0.5%.

Comment: Sorry - can you clarify what the word "95% confident" means in this context?... is it assuming some distribution around a true mean - like [uniform or normal errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_uncertainty#Type_A_and_Type_B_evaluation_of_uncertainty) or some such?  Is "95% confident" really implying an actual confidence interval, or is this really saying something else? [And you may not know answers to all these, but on the other hand may be in a position to suggest pointers to the information]. It's not clear what the underlying 'model' of the uncertainty is here

Comment: I think the 95% is a distribution about the true mean, as you suggest.

Comment: A distribution of observed values about the true value? If so, the shape of the distribution will matter somewhat.

Comment: Sure. Assuming the distribution is gaussian?